# bcrypt.compare ( ) always returning false

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I have tried both **bcrypt** (version 5.0.0) and **bcryptjs** (version 2.4.3) to hash and compare passwords. But the compare function in both the packages always returns **false**.

**Hashing**

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);
  this.passwordConfirm = undefined;
  next();
});
```

**Comparing**

```
userSchema.methods.checkPassword = async function (inputPass, hashedPass) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(inputPass, hashedPass);
};
```

**Update**
The issue seems to be gone now on my other projects with exact same setup.

Comment: The usual scheme for passwords is that you store a hashed version of the password and then when a password is submitted you hash it and then compare the two hashes.  In your `checkPassword` method, I assume one of these is the previously stored hash and the other one is an incoming password.  If so, that needs to be hashed before comparing it.  You can't compare a hash to a plain password.

Comment: I think you are not making hash of input password before taking comparision of input password and user password.First you have to make hash of input password as well then compare both password it should return true if input password is correct

Comment: @jfriend00
hash method generates a unique hash each time, even if a same input is provided in it.
So even when I first hash the input password and then compare it to the already hashed password stored in DB, it returns false.

Also, earlier I've used bcrypt in the same way as I used it here. That time it worked, but all of sudden it stopped working.
Also, there is no official update regarding any change in the way the bcrypt compare works. I don't understand why it stopped working.

Comment: You are clearly doing something wrong if the hash is different every time when given the same input data.  The hashing function would be fairly useless if that was the case.  I suspect you're not starting with the same input data each time or doing something else wrong.  Perhaps you're hashing a hash or something like that.

Comment: @jfriend00
I checked but there is nothing wrong with the hash generating implementation. It's just the way bcrypt works. It generates new salt every time it receives an input and therefore each time a unique hash is created even if the provided input is the same.
I suspect there is something wrong with the "compare" function because earlier in Jan 2021, it was working completely fine this way. But now, all of sudden it is working in this weird way where it always returns false.

Comment: Or maybe something is wrong with the storage mechanism and you aren't getting back an accurate original hashed value?

Comment: I have this exact same issue right now. It worked until today. Did you find a solution @SachinYadav ?

Comment: No I didn't found any solutions to this. But for some reason, bcryptjs works fine on my other projects with same config and setup.

Answer (score 0):

you can't using await function with return, just try

```
userSchema.methods.checkPassword = async function (inputPass, hashedPass) {
  let isValid = await bcrypt.compare(inputPass, hashedPass);
  return isValid;
};
```

Comment: Using await with return is not an issue. But I tried this approach as well and it didn't work.